# ¿Como puedo trabajar un projecto QT que no tiene el archivo para que reconozca el proyecto?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

ando trabajando con un proyecto QT, pero este aunque en sus archivos cpp y .h tiene las librerias que require para trabajar con QT como #include . No tiene el archivo para poder importar todo el proyecto en QTCreator.

Espero haberme explicado bien y espero que alguien tenga la respuesta

Comment: podrías decir ¿Que entorno de desarrollo utilizas?

Comment: QT creator 5.9.1 en Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt creator (al igual que cualquier otro IDE) no puede importar un proyecto a partir únicamente de los includes de los ficheros.

¿por qué? Varias razones:

- Los includes solo indican dependencias, pero estas dependencias pueden no formar parte del proyecto (librerías externas)
- Los includes no indican la configuración del proyecto (nombres definidos, orden de compilación, nombre del binario resultante, optimizaciones, ...)

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un proyecto nuevo y a continuación añadir todos los archivos pertenecientes a dicho proyecto. No olvides indicar las dependencias externas (librerías de terceros).